# How to upload WordPress child theme to XAMPP + Bitnami + Mac OS?

Tags: wordpress, macos, xampp, themes, bitnami

Everything was going so well: installed XAMPP on Mac (OS 10.10.2). Installed Bitnami WordPress module. Imported existing WordPress site (this site is already live). Then imported/installed the theme I want to modify. All good up to that point.

Now I want to create a child theme. Following the [instructions from Themify](http://themify.me/docs/child-themes), which are great. BUT: I can't open the htdocs directory within the wordpress dir that was installed by the Bitnami module. No permissions.

There's [a help page](https://wiki.bitnami.com/applications/bitnami_wordpress_stack#How_to_edit_the_WordPress_files.3f), but it's not helping me. Reason 1: I open FileZilla, I FTP to localhost, but the wordpress dir is nowhere to be found there. Reason 2: I try to follow their `sudo chown` instructions but the path is not valid for me. I tried:

`$ sudo chown daemon:daemon Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress/htdocs`

... but no luck. "No such file or directory." I can find this folder in the Finder ([see screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfD2J.jpg)), but I can't seem to access it from the command line. (Is that because XAMPP is in the Applications directory?)

In case it's not obvious, I am doing all this to muck around with my child theme offline. But I can't get my child theme folder into the wp-content/themes folder, because I can't FTP or access the folder directly through the Finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to change permissions through the Mac "Get Info" panel. Doh!!

["Get Info" panel, unlocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naLtO.png)

[See screencap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twBct.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try and put a Leading slash at the front of the directory listing so run this instead:

sudo chown daemon:daemon /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress/htdocs

Comment: That also didn't work. BUT!! I was able to change permissions through the Mac "Get Info" panel! Problem solved! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/themes/your-child theme` and set permission of your child theme folder to writable to everyone.